# Any monitoring software which traces IIS & freely available 

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp-classic

In continuation to last question - My site goes slow and stops access certain services externally if we check the Process monitor we see that it is normally due to the ‘w3p.exe’ process – which is the background process for running the website – it regularly reaches 99/100% - killing the process/restarting the WebPublishing service reolves tis – my webhost says this can only be due to bad coding ....can someone comment on this ??…

Wanted to know any monitoring software which traces IIS & freely available ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net then you can use the built in Asp.Net tracing to find out things like the size of your viewstate and the where the time is spent while rendering a page. There are various ways of enabling this depending on what your needs are: see http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/tracefunctionality.aspx

Answer (score 0):

99% CPU is not going to occur if you have an inefficient page or two.  99% CPU utilization happens when you have a bug. 
If it does not happen on your local server, but only in the hosted environment, then you will have to resort to the old school detective approaches.  Tracing, removing portions of code, and so on - til you find the source of the problem.